# java swing GUI popupMenu sit above the interface of another program or file window

Tags: java, macos, swing

I am working on a Swing GUI appication on mac osx. There is a proble, when i right click on open a popup on my Application , and then i click on other application. my pop is still open and i can work on other GUI.

As shown in image.

[image]

Which should be the best way to resolve this issue? Should i close all popups on my window while focus goes away to other program? or something else.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581314/how-do-you-hide-a-swing-popup-when-you-click-somewhere-else) can help.

Comment: How exactly you create menu and display it? Please post some code that represents the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used apple mac os property to pin my JMenu to Os menu. and all worked perfect.

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
```

This link is very useful for swing app looking like native OS.

http://www.devdaily.com/apple/mac/java-mac-native-look/References.shtml