# How to close the popup DatePicker when I click somewhere else in JDatePicker in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

I download and use `JDatePicker` (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/). I put it in `JTextField` and when I click anywhere else from the popup the popup doesn't close (like all other popups).I try to find out, how I can close the popup but I did not find something?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please follow the link http://jdatepicker.org to find the latest binary download via maven central repo, the project binaries are no longer distributed via sourceforge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit Dec. 2014:**
This issue has been fixed by the developers of `JDatePicker`. See juanheyns's answer below.

After looking into the source code of `JDatePicker` I think this is not possible without changing the source code of `JDatePicker`.

Implementing that behavior requires some minor changes to the source code of the class `net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl` (line 209):

```
    /**
     * Called internally to popup the dates.
     */
    private void showPopup() {
        // This is the replaced code:
//      if (popup == null){
//          PopupFactory fac = new PopupFactory();
//          Point xy = getLocationOnScreen();
//          datePanel.setVisible(true); 
//          popup = fac.getPopup(this, datePanel, (int) xy.getX(), (int) (xy.getY()+this.getHeight()));
//          popup.show();
//      }
        // This is new code
        JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();
        pop.add(datePanel);
        pop.show(this, this.getX(), this.getY() + this.getHeight());
    }
```

Please also have a look at [How do you hide a Swing Popup when you click somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581314/how-do-you-hide-a-swing-popup-when-you-click-somewhere-else) for some more details.

Answer (score 3):

This has been logged as an issue on the project github page:
https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker/issues/29

It has been fixed and will be part of next release (1.4.0):
https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker/commit/4fa441a8e06691e4a00573379ea4d218710d7d1a

Comment: When will the new version come out, if at all?

Comment: Is there a temporary fix? When is the v1.4.0 coming out?